# Unable to fetch TIMESTAMP(6) with local time zone using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core for ef-core 6

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, scaffolding, ef-core-6.0, oracle-manageddataaccess

Columns of type TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE are scaffolded to DateTimeOffset when using Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore data provider, but when fetching using linq I'm getting an exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.    at
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDateTimeOffset(Int32
> i)    at lambda_method332(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader ,
> ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Table configuration:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<TestTable>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasNoKey();

    entity.ToTable("TEST_TABLE");

    entity.Property(e => e.TestColumnDatetime)
                        .HasColumnType("DATE")
                        .HasColumnName("TEST_COLUMN_DATETIME");

    entity.Property(e => e.TestColumnNumber)
                        .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                        .HasColumnName("TEST_COLUMN_NUMBER");

    entity.Property(e => e.TestColumnTimestamp)
                        .HasPrecision(6)
                        .HasColumnName("TEST_COLUMN_TIMESTAMP");

    entity.Property(e => e.TestColumnTimestampLtz)
                        .HasColumnType("TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE")
                        .HasColumnName("TEST_COLUMN_TIMESTAMP_LTZ");

    entity.Property(e => e.TestColumnVarchar)
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasMaxLength(10)
                        .IsUnicode(false)
                        .HasColumnName("TEST_COLUMN_VARCHAR");
});
```

Class:

```cs
public partial class TestTable
{
    public decimal TestColumnNumber { get; set; }
    public string TestColumnVarchar { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TestColumnDatetime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TestColumnTimestamp { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? TestColumnTimestampLtz { get; set; }
}
```

Scaffolding command :

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "connection-string" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore --table TEST_TABLE --context TempContext --context-dir OracleEfCoreData --output-dir OracleEfCoreDomain
```

Both columns of oracle type `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` are successfully fetched in dotnet but `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` doesn't work. I have tried reomving precision and column type from the model configuration but the error persists.
I'm running a dotnet core api in my local machine, connecting to on-premise db server

EDIT:
If I change type of TestColumnTimestampLtz to DateTime while preserving the generated ModelBuilder configuration then the exception is this:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The property
> 'TestTable.TestColumnTimestampLtz' is of type 'DateTime?' which is not
> supported by the current database provider. Either change the property
> CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or
> by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidatePropertyMapping(IModel
> model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel
> model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.OracleModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelRuntimeInitializer.Initialize(IModel
> model, Boolean designTime, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 validationLogger)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
> serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
> serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
> serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
> serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
> serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
> serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Comment: What's the *actual* query code? What's the actual full exception text? Post the actual result of `Exception.ToString()` not just parts of the message. The full text includes the error location, any inner exceptions and a stack trace with the exceptions that resulted in the exception.

Comment: BTW `WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` means there's no time zone and hence no offset. The time is assumed to be local *whatever that may mean to the application*.  Have you tried with `DateTime` instead of `DateTimeOffset` ?

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos If you meant changing the type to DateTime then  I have added the exception on what I assumed you meant  as an edit, I was not sure where the right place for it was.